# Cypress modal doesn't close

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, cypress

I've read 5-6 relevant Stackoverflow threads, none appear to pertain to this (famous last words).

Cypress 12.3.0 (was happening on v9 so I upgraded, but the issue persists).

Problem only occurs in automation.

Test conducted in headed mode (Cypress > Edge).

1. Click delete icon
2. Modal appears
3. Click delete button in modal

Expected result:

Action performed, modal closes.

Actual result:

Action performed, modal doesn't close.

Troubleshooting:

I added a command to close the modal using the modal's X button = Cypress can't find it.

If I don't add the above command, the succeeding test steps cannot click on elements because the modal that allegedly doesn't exist is covering them!

In Cypress > Edge, I can interact with and inspect the modal's elements.

This is crazy.

Code:

```
cy.contains('button', 'Delete Queue')
.click();
```

No iframes involved.

I'm enquiring internally to establish what JavaScript event or logic is closing the modal so I can trigger that. Or close the modal if it can be found with JavaScript...

Just wondered if you guys have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the HTML of the page with the modal open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whatever reason the app wouldn't close the modal after deleting the queue so I closed it myself *using the correct CSS selector*.

Comment: What is the mean of that? can you explain? are you closing yourself in the js code or cypress please could you give an example

Answer (score 0):

Added `cy.wait` after the modal was opened and before selecting an element on modal.

This resolved the issue for me:

```
cy.get('.sc-gsDKAQ.sc-dUbtfd.exemMH.dTJusa.glowButton').click() --> this opens the modal
cy.wait(5000)


cy.get('.newElement').contains('Text Input').click() --> selecting an element on modal
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can resolve your problem :

```js
cy.contains('button', 'Delete Queue')
.click();
cy.get('[data-test-id="modal-close-button"]')
.click();
```

Let me know if it works.